# Button from other layout not respond

Tags: android, layout, cardlayout

I´m working on two layouts: the main one and another one (a card layout). I included the card layout inside the main layout, with the following code:

```
  <include
        android:id="@+id/miPrueba"
        layout="@layout/card_product_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
```

This works fine, but I have buttons in my main layout and I need to use them. When I try to find them, using `findViewByIdid` from my card layout, I use this code:

```
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.card_product_details, null);
   Button prueba = (Buttton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
    prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast por defecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

What I get is nothing, no error, no null pointer exception, nothing. Simple, it does not respond when I click it.

How I can solve it?

Comment: put your whole xml where the layout is inluded

Comment: I could, but I´m pretty sure that the XML is perfect, I just have a problem when I try to catch the button from the external xml to the main activity. I think the error is in my MainActivity, when I do the inflate.

Comment: then take object of layoutManager using context.getSystemService and then inflate the lay6out instead of this.

Comment: When debugging, did you check whether the onClick method is called putting a checkpoint in the line with Toast.makeText?

Answer (score 0):

Need more of your code but from what you have given the reason you are having this problem is that the card doesn't have the button `buttonId`

When you are creating 
`View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.card_product_details, null);`

Comment: I forgot put that XML, sorry, anyway, when I debug the aplication, I get something, the object is not null.